# What defines the timeout period in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, timeout

Say, I have PHP running on an Apache. When someone makes a client request (doesn't matter how), what defines the amount of time that the client will wait for, the script to run? **Is this option of an Apache, of a PHP or is defined by the client himself?**
Also, what if the script is called via curl?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Just so you are aware of the implications, allowing the client to do so would be enough to have hackers enjoying many a wet dream.

Answer (score 1):

See PHP [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the **max_execution_time** value defined in the php.ini.

Please note:

> This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

You might also be interested in **max_input_time** (set via php.ini)

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. It is measured from the moment of receiving all data on the server to the start of script execution.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in `php.ini`, parameter is called `max_execution_time`.

You can change it with  [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) OR in [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php) directly.

But, in fact you are asking about

> the amount of time that the client will wait for, the script to run

and imho, it is infinite. I have never seen such a moment when server was running script and browser refused to wait. The main is to keep script running on server.

Comment: what if the script is called via curl?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze, `max_execution_time` effects CURL too. If you want to get data from server B to server A with CURL, in case if server B runs script and server A is waiting for respond, then `max_execution_time` must be set on both sides. If CURL is getting too big data from server B, but this time server B does not run script, changing limit only on server A will help.

Comment: @nikoloz :) you must understand that `max_execution_time` is server side limit, not user side. If script is called anyhow it will run until it reaches `max_execution_time`.

Comment: oh, missed: there is `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` option for cURL too.